# What's the error with my code here? I can't seem to get it to work.

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

The program should sort the numbers from lowest to highest. I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
n=int(input("Enter any positive integer, 0 to stop: "))
while n!=0:
    anyList.append(n)
    n=int(input("Enter any positive integer, 0 to stop: "))

L=len(anyList)
for j in range(L):
    c=999999999
    for i in range(L):
        if anyList[i]<check:
            c=anyList[i]
            p=i
    anyList[p]=999999999
    newList.append(c)

print (newList)
```

Comment: Where do you define `anyList`? Where do you define `check`? Where do you define `newList`?

Comment: *How* it does or doesn't work ? Please, include expected output, desired and actual output.

Comment: I would use Python's standard sort function: `sort(anyList) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
n=1
anyList = []
while n!=0 :
  n = input("Enter any positive integer, 0 to stop: ")
  anyList.append(n)    
for i in range(0, len(anyList)):
  for j in range(0, len(anyList)-i-1):
    if(anyList[j] > anyList[j+1]):
      tmp = anyList[j];
      anyList[j] = anyList[j + 1];
      anyList[j + 1] = tmp;
print(anyList)
```